# With Xcode 9, do I need to still create a .gitignore file?

Tags: xcode9

Xcode 9 is tightly integrated with GitHub. In preferences, under Source Control settings, git tab we can now set the files to be ignored during commits.

I'd rather assumed that Xcode would use this information to create a .gitignore file as part of the process of setting a new project up to use Source Control - it does, after all, create the project and make the initial commit automatically.

Is this wishful thinking or have I missed something?

(just to be clear, I know what should go in the file)

Comment: Have you tried using the Git tab to do it, and see what winds up on Github? It should be pretty obvious if Xcode is creating/modifying `.gitignore`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was asking!  (nothing ends up on GitHub)  I could see some form of logic saying "if Xcode isn't committing it, then you don't need an actual .gitignore" but if that is the reasoning then I'm not convinced.